# Morphia Aggregation Pipeliene

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I need a little help with an aggregation pipeline in morphia. This is what I have in mongo:

```
db.transacciones.aggregate([
{$match:
    {"$and":[
        {"usuario._id": "xxx@gmail.com"}, 
        {"status":{"$ne":"ERROR"}}]}}, 
{$sort:{"date": -1}}, 
{$group:{"ordenId", "transaction" : {$first:"$$ROOT"}}}, 
{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$transaction"}}])
```

Ok, this is what I have in morphia:

```
Query<TransaccionP2P> match = ds.getQueryFactory().createQuery(ds);
match.and(match.criteria("usuario._id").equal(usuarioId),
          match.criteria("status").notEqual(Status.ST_ERROR));

Sort sort = Sort.descending("date");

Group group = grouping("transaction", Accumulator.accumulator("$first", (Object)"$$ROOT"));

Projection[] projections = {
            Projection.projection("_id", "$transaction._id"),
            ...
};

AggregationPipeline pipeline = ds.createAggregation(TransaccionP2P.class)
            .match(match)
            .sort(sort)
            .group("orden._id", group)
            .project(projections);

Iterator<TransaccionP2P> iterator =  pipeline.aggregate(TransaccionP2P.class);
List<TransaccionP2P> transacciones = new ArrayList<>();
iterator.forEachRemaining(transacciones::add);
```

I have managed to construct this pipeline with the stackoverflow articles I found because I couldn't find a good example in Morphia documentation but I have these problems:

- Morphia doesn't seem to have support for $replaceRoot so I have to create the projection field by field.
- The transaction variable in the group aggregate is not recognized in the projection step.

Here is the projection exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 17276: 'Use of undefined variable: transaction'.
```

I haven't managed to find the correct way of making the projection for 'transaction' to be recognized.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it works, I get an object with only the Ids

Comment: Is that what you expect? Would u mind posting the result?

Comment: Its a big object but the mongo result is something like this: { "_id" : NumberLong(11), "orden" : { .. }, ...} the morphia result is {id:2, orden:null ...} and everything else is null and the Id is not the object Id, its the order Id we are using for grouping

Comment: why don't you print ur Morphia query to understand what's doing? I don't remember how to do in Morphia but u can set the profiling level to 2 and query: db.setProfilingLevel(2); db.system.profile.find()

Comment: Thanks! that was the problem! the project was translating to "$$transaction._id", I removed the $ and it worked!